# Nhibernate v2.1.2 criteria fetch adding some days to modifiedon > datetimenow

Tags: c#, nhibernate-criteria

Want to achieve something like
**ModifiedDate.AddDays(20) > current datetime **

Where the modifiedondate is added with a configurable value and which is again compared with whether it is greater than the current datetime.

For example in DB I have modifieddate as 2nd , adding 20 to it makes it 22nd and now would be checking if this 22nd is greater than current datetime. Can use inline sql/hql in code, but want to achieve the same with criteria. Please share your views.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution searching the examples :)

```
cr.Add(Restrictions.Gt(
                    Projections.SqlFunction(
                        new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Date,
                                                "DateAdd(Day," + strParamVal + ", ?1)"),NHibernateUtil.Date,
                        Projections.Property("ModifiedDate")),DateTime.Now));
```